# Proper way of referencing multiple items in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Assume you have a relation that needs to somehow reference any (variable) number of different items in another table (by their keys). How would this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you would usually have an intermediate table.  Here is an example schema

```
Table - Question
QuestionID
Title
Body
Date

Table - Tag
TagID
TagName

Table - QuestionTag
QuestionID
TagID
```

In a schema such as this, The question table contains questions.  The tag table contains a list of tags that can be applied to the question (like on this site). And the QuestionTag links the two together, so that a question can be linked to any number of tags.  To get a specific questions with it's tags, you could do the following

```
SELECT Question.QuestionID, Question.Title,Question.Body,Question.Date,GROUP_CONCAT(Tag.TagName)
FROM Question
LEFT JOIN QuestionTag 
ON Question.QuestionID = QuestionTag.QuestionID
LEFT JOIN Tag 
ON QuestionTag.TagID = Tag.TagID
WHERE Question.QuestionID=@QuestionID
GROUP BY Question.QuestionID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an example:

For a book store, an author can have any number of books.

```
+Table_Author+
--------------
id
name
--------------

+Table_Book+
------------
id
title
author_id <--this is the key!
------------
```

Then you can get every book for a particular author:

```
SELECT books.title FROM Table_Book books WHERE books.author_id=2
```

**Content type approach:**

```
+Table_contentype+
-------------------
id
name
table_name_from_model --don't know how to properly call it
-------------------

+Table_Person+
---------------
id
name
---------------

+Table_Person_Objects+
-----------------------
id
person_id
content_type_id
object_id
-----------------------

Then your person can have, for example:

+Table_contentype+
--------------------------------------
id          name          table_name
--------------------------------------
1           Item A         items_a_table
1           Item B         items_b_table
--------------------------------------

+Table_Person_Objects+
--------------------------------------------------
id  person_id    content_type_id      object_id
--------------------------------------------------
1       1              1                 1
2       1              1                 4
3       1              2                 2
4       2              1                 1
--------------------------------------------------
```

This way, Person 1 can have 2 Items_A (1,4) 1 Item_B(2) and person 2 can have the same Item_A(1) that Person 1 has.

This I think is the most flexible scheme i can thought.

Comment: The data I am using doesn't have a static relation like that. It's more of a person to a person's belongings sort of relation. Something like a person a owns these items, while person b owns x items (some of the items can/will be the same)

Comment: Oh, ok. You should put that in your question. Then you can use something similar to the concept of "content types" from django. I'll add it to the answer

Comment: How should that be phrased? I would like to make sure my question is helpful for others

Answer (score 1):

1. Can you please provide an example? Maybe your schema can be refactored so that it does not need such fancy constraints?
2. Obvious: define multiple constraints, as many as you need.
3. Define triggers that would prevent rows that don't satisfy the relation from occurring in the table.

But I still suspect that the table structure can be redefined to simplify things.

Comment: Best way to describe it is a table of 'people' that have many 'items', but these items can also be owned by other people too.

Comment: @TheDog: one my rule of thumb is to name your table as singular: 'person' and 'item', this simplifies understanding of many-to-anything relations (for me). Solution for your problem is simple, you've already accepted it :)